# EJBCA 7_4_3_2 database connectivity problem

Tags: java, ant, wildfly, ejbca

I am using EJBCA 7_4_3_2.
My goal is to connect to a postgres database
but I keep on getting the following error output:

```
root@guardian:/opt/kais/mes/install/guardian/ejbca/ejbca_ce_7_4_3_2# ant deploydb -Ddatabase=/opt/kais/mes/install/guardian/ejbca/ejbca_ce_7_4_3_2/conf/database.properties
Buildfile: /opt/kais/mes/install/guardian/ejbca/ejbca_ce_7_4_3_2/build.xml

customejbca.message:
     [echo] No custom changes to merge.

appserver.error.message:
     [echo] 'appserver.type' could not be detected or is not configured. Glassfish 3.1, Glassfish 4.0, JBoss 7.1.1, JBoss EAP 6.1, 6.2, 6.3, 6.4, WildFly 8, 9, 10 can be detected. (Is 'appserver.home' configured?)

BUILD FAILED
Target "deploydb" does not exist in the project "ejbca".
```

I took a look at the build.xml file but i am not sure which target is used to connect to a database.

Can someone help me out?

Comment: It looks like you need to specify a value for `appserver.home`

Comment: i solved it by adding a -D appserver.home=/path/to/my/wildfly/home/dir

Answer (score 0):

deploydb is not a valid command. You should read the installation instructions in the documentation. PostgreSQL is mentioned there.
https://doc.primekey.com/ejbca/ejbca-installation